# Angular 7 to Angular 8 migration

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

As i have migrated my code from Angular 7 to Angular 8 and the migration is done but when i am running the application using npm start then it gives the below error

```
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.1 was found instead.
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

So for that i am trying to downgrade the typescript version from 3.5.1 to 3.4.0 using `npm i typescript@3.4.0 --save-dev --save-exact`

It gives the below error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-11T06_02_56_125Z-debug.log
```

The file have these contents

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'typescript@3.4.0',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.4.0
4 verbose npm-session 34e826751150af7e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 624ms (from cache)
8 silly registry:manifest no matching version for typescript@3.4.0 in the cache. Forcing revalidation.
9 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 717ms
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@3.4.0 No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0
11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3ms
12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4809ms
13 verbose type version
14 verbose stack typescript: No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0
14 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:101:11)
14 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\manifest.js:43:18
14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
14 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
14 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
14 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
14 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
15 verbose cwd E:\ng72ng8\Fxt\Web\src\main\ui\material
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "typescript@3.4.0" "--save-dev" "--save-exact"
18 verbose node v12.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ETARGET
21 error notarget No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0
22 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
22 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can anyone help me out this on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: `"typescript": "~3.4.3"`
add this to your package.json file and try npm install.I also had your problem and that's what i did, simply overwritten the version number and `npm install`-ed . If it still gives errors, try deleting your `node_modules` and run install again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no version `3.4.0` of Typescript, either set it to a different version (can be viewed under the "Versions" tab here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), or make the version something like `~3.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

> Angular 8 supports the TypeScript 3.4 or above version. So, if we want
>   to use Angular 8 for our application, then we need to first upgrade
>   the TypeScript to 3.4 or above.

Typescript 3.4.0 version is on development mode, you can see here [typescript version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript?activeTab=versions), so you need to change your Typescript version from `3.4.0` to `3.4.3` in your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `"typescript": "~3.4.5"` in a angular 8 application. For me it is working as expected.
Try upgrading all the dependencies which can be upgraded by using :

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

**OR**

```
ng update --all
```

Sometimes this command throws library mismatching issues in that case you can use something like this

```
ng update --force
```

This command will update all the dependencies forcefully, rest of the peer dependencies can be updated manually.